Probabiliy density (Histogram) of measured data
The measured data from a gas sensor measurement system, in the absence of any excitation is as shown below. The data set consists of n = 65535 samples. 
The sensor output is discretized by the acquisition system. The amplitude histogram is therefore a PMF which is as shown below.

The mean and variance of the data are :  $\mu$ = 0.0007029 and $\sigma^2$ = 2.240D-09. The PMF of the data resembles Binomial distribution. However, since measurement errors and noise are typically Gaussian, and the number of measurements, n being quite large (n = 65535), it is reasonable to assume the samples to be Gaussian distributed with mean and variance $\mu$ = 0.0007029 and $\sigma^2$ = 2.240D-09 (from data). The Gaussian pdf is also plotted below.

One can observe the huge difference between the scales (y-axis) if the measured PMF and the Gaussian computed using the mean and variance evaluated using the data. How to understand the difference between the probability plots ?

this is really just stochastic, not signal processing: the area under the curve needs to be 1, right? Same as the sum of your PMF "bars". Now, the intervals of the Gaussian curve that "integrate" to be (approximately) the same as your bars are very narrow, ca. 2.5·10⁻⁵; thus, for the integral to be approximately the same value as the PMF centered in that interval, the PDF needs to be pretty high. This seems to be perfectly logical to me :)

Note that usually, when we say "n is large for this Binomial Distribution", that we don't just get 13 different values as you do here. Are you sure this is really binomially distributed? If so, what is the $p$ of success to your n = 65535?


resembles Binomial distribution

Not really. It IS discrete and somewhat bell shaped, but its asymmetric around the center tab and the underlying mechanism for its discreteness is completely different.

it is reasonable to assume the samples to be Gaussian distributed

No. Its reasonable to assume that the original noise process that you sampled is Gaussian, but the sampling process itself adds sizeable amount of quantization noise and turns a continuous PDF into a discrete one. Technically, that's true for any sampling process but if the quantization interval is small enough we can neglect it. Here we can not. To summarize: the analog noise is Gaussian, the samples are clearly not.

One can observe the huge difference between the scales (y-axis) ... How to understand the difference between the probability plots ?

One is discrete, one is continuous. The sum over each must come out to be one: since you have a lot more non-zero values in the continuous one, the numbers will be a lot smaller. You can roughly interpret that every value in the discrete one represents and entire interval and the difference in scaling will roughly be the distance between the discrete peaks.
